# Why i get Erreur(196,24): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'C_MOTIFS'

Tags: oracle, plsql

i created a cursor  C_MOTIFS and get Erreur(196,24): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'C_MOTIFS'

```
Cursor C_MOTIFS(num_doss varchar2 ) Is
                    
               SELECT
                    f.protocol_nr,
               CASE
                   WHEN folder_state IN ('09', '10','37','16','07')
                   THEN
                       codes.justification_code
                 
               END AS code_motif,
               
               CASE
                   WHEN folder_state IN ('09', '10','37','16','07')
                   THEN
                       code.justification_code_descr    
               END AS descr_motif
               
          FROM his_folder f
               
         WHERE  f.FOLDER_TYPE_CODE ='10' and f.protocol_nr=num_doss;
```

```
FOR SM IN C_MOTIFS
                    LOOP
                        ret_motifs.extend;
                        ret_motifs(nb_motifs):= MOTIF(
                                            SM.code_motif,
                                            SM.descr_motif
                                            );
                        nb_motifs := nb_motifs +1;
                    END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created the parameterized cursor.

```
Cursor C_MOTIFS(num_doss varchar2 ) IS
```

Either remove parameter from cursor

```
Cursor C_MOTIFS IS
```

Or pass some varchar2 value while calling that cutsor:

```
FOR SM IN C_MOTIFS(varchar_value)
```